# Running php script in jsp page

Tags: java, php, jsp, tomcat, php-java-bridge

> Fatal Error: Failed to start PHP ["php-cgi", "-v"], reason:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""php-cgi"" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\user"): CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file
>   specificato Could not start FCGI server: java.io.IOException: PHP not
>   found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v] 
>   php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

I would like to run php scripts within a jsp page but it returns this error. I would like to know how this issue can be resolved

Comment: `PHP not found. Please install php-cgi` -- seems clear enough?

Comment: How do you install it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php